# Excel - Return dates in a list that are within 1 year of another date

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to write a formula that would return a date (B) from a list if that date is within 1 year of another date (A).  If there are no dates in the list that are within 1 year of date A, then date B will simply be date A plus 1 year (365.25 days).

For example: My list is [2/15/16, 12/26/17, 5/15/19].  If date A is 1/1/16, then I want Date B to equal 2/15/16.  If Date A was 2/15/16, then Date B would be 2/15/17.

The closest I've gotten is:
`=IF(MIN(L:L)-A<=365.25,MIN(L:L),A+365.25)`, but obviously this won't work beyond the minimum date. I need to check against the whole list of dates, not just the minimum date.

My end goal is to make a list like this (column A after the first date is just the previous B:

```
 From (A) - To (B)  
 1/1/15 - 1/1/16  
 1/1/16 - 2/15/16  
 2/15/16 - 2/15/17  
2/15/17 - 12/26/17
```

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((($A$2:$A$4-C2)<365.25)*(($A$2:$A$4-C2)>0)),$A$2:$A$4),EDATE(C2,12))
```

Column A has the list of dates, C2 has Date A. Running some more dates in column C, copying the formula down:

[image]